# Cost of EEG devices suitable for neurolinguistic research

Tags: linguistics, eeg

What is the cost of an EEG device (electrodes and other indispensable hardware, software if available for standard office computers, or a whole package with a dedicated computer and software) that is of suitable quality for neurolinguistic research? My own attempts to find information on this were futile. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) article quotes low-cost devices from US$ 100 onwards, but I'm guessing the very cheap ones are of rather limited use for research. There is also an [OPenEEG](http://openeeg.sourceforge.net/doc/) project, but I'm looking for an out-of-the-box solution. The commercial suppliers I found online do not quote any prices.

I just need a rough estimate to what amount of money is necessary to do any publishable academic research, and how much solution for average research needs would cost - such as 500 Euros/Dollars, 1,000, 10,000...?

Answer (score 5):

We were looking for an EEG device few years ago. The commercial offers were between 20,000 EUR for a 32 passive electrode to 50,000 EUR for an 64/128 active electrode. This included everything except the computers - some offers were without off-line data processing software. I never considered the EEG systems that were not mentioned in the method section of my research domain. And beware of the local regulations and ethical considerations concerning home-made devices for recording human biological signal.

Answer (score 4):

An old question, but there has been some recent developments by third-parties and now cheaper and hopefully just-as-accurate EEGs exist.

From [Are recent affordable EEG devices any good?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8419/are-recent-affordable-eeg-devices-any-good?lq=1) we see the [Emotiv System](http://emotiv.com/store/) and a [paper that can attest to its accuracy](https://peerj.com/articles/38/).

We also have [OpenBCI](http://www.openbci.com/), an open-source EEG catered to makers, which has recently been funded successfully on [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/openbci/openbci-an-open-source-brain-computer-interface-fo).

Both EEGs can be had for < $500, but both are relatively new in the scene so it would be interesting to see how they compare to traditional methods.

Comment: I'd add that it depends a bit on the OP's own subdiscipline; if looking to do publishable academic work in cognition & neurophysiology, these devices will probably not cut it in traditional publishing venues. If the OP is in brain-computer interfaces or any less traditionally cognitive-psych area, they may suffice.